# JButton changes size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a `JFrame`, and whenever I switch from one `JFrame` using a `JButton` it starts out normally, but whenever I create a new instance of the first `JFrame`, the `JButton` is in an incorrect location and is the wrong size.

Example on startup[image: on startup]

[image: when instanced a second time]

and when another one is created
Code:

```
public class Menu extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int Number_of_Participants = 0;
    protected JPanel window = new JPanel();
    double p;
    private JButton Participants;
    private Rectangle rParticipants;

    protected int Button_width = 240;
    protected int Button_height = 48;
    boolean running = false;
    Thread thread;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public Menu() {
        window.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(window);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/BG.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        generateFiles();
        drawButtons();

        startMenu();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public void drawButtons() {
        rParticipants = new Rectangle(520, 12, Button_width, Button_height);
        Participants = new JButton("A");
        Participants.setBounds(rParticipants);
        window.add(Participants);
        Participants.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                new Participant(Number_of_Participants);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**Participant.java**  ***extends***  **Menu.java**

```
int Participant_ID;

public Participant(int Participant_ID) {
    super();
    this.Participant_ID = Participant_ID;
}
```

makes a JButton that goes back to Menu.java

Comment: Post more infos (preferably an http://sscce.org/ ) - What layout are you using? You should call `setVisible(true)` at the end, after all components have been added.

Comment: We have to show us some code. We aren't witches.

Comment: one moment, i will add it, Done

Comment: Avoid `null` layouts.  `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which may be overriding your settings

Comment: @Marco13  Great suggestion.  Note that from the 1st of March, the SSCCE.org will disappear forever.  The official replacement is a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE) here at SE.

Comment: Although I could not reproduce the error here, you should at least place the line `frame.setVisible(true)` to be the LAST line in the `Menu` constructor - I assume this will already solve the problem. Apart from that, there are so many issues with this code (naming conventions, static state, layout, inheritance, ...) that I'll insert another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your problem is most likely related to the call to `setVisible(true)`. This should always be the LAST call in the constructor. Particularly, it should only be called AFTER all components have been added to the frame.

Apart from that, from the code that you posted, it seems like you want to switch through a seqence of frames, starting with a "main" menu, and then going through one frame for each "Participant". This intention could already be considered as questionable, because closing and disposing a JFrame just in order to create a new one does not seem to be very elegant. Most likely, a more elegant solution would be possible with a `CardLayout` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

However, some general hints:

- Create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread
- Don't extend JFrame. Instead, create a JFrame and fill it as needed
- Don't implement Runnable with your top level class
- Obey the standardJavaNamingConventions!
- Don't try to do manual layouts with setBounds

This code is still not "beautiful", but at least shows how the goal of switching through several frames might be achieved, taking into account these points

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MenuExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JPanel mainMenuPanel = new MainMenuPanel();
                createAndShowFrame(mainMenuPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    static void createAndShowFrame(JPanel panel)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JButton createNextParticipantButton(
        final JComponent container, final int nextID)
    {
        JButton nextParticipantButton = new JButton("New Participant");
        nextParticipantButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                Window window = 
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(container);
                window.dispose();

                ParticipantPanel participantPanel = 
                    new ParticipantPanel(nextID);
                createAndShowFrame(participantPanel);
            }
        });
        return nextParticipantButton;
    }

}

class MainMenuPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MainMenuPanel() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(MenuExample.createNextParticipantButton(this, 0));
    }
}

class ParticipantPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final int participantID;

    public ParticipantPanel(int participantID) 
    {
        this.participantID = participantID;

        add(new JLabel("Add the contents for participant "+participantID));
        add(MenuExample.createNextParticipantButton(this, participantID+1));
    }
}
```